# Woocommerce - My Account Issues

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Ammended Question after digging further...

I am having issues accessing My Account as a customer...

I was doing some tests on my website, I have an Admin account as well as a Customer account set up·

When I visit www.mysite.com/my-account and login with my admin details, it works fine, takes me to my account... If I use the customer details, it does not log me in, instead it redirects me to the home page.

I have tried this on multiple browsers and get the same result, I have also asked a few of my friends, who have customer accounts, to try and they get the same outcome.

I cant figure out what the issue is, as it appears to be working correctly and checking the input details against the data base... I tried using my customer login email with an incorrect password, the page reloaded and it advised me that the login details where incorrect.

I get a similar effect when registering a new account.
I register the details and it then redirects me to the homepage. It does not show that the account has been registered, however the registration details DO get emailed out. If I then try to login and access My account using those details, I get the same effect as above.

Hopefully someone can help me sort this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try/check the following.

1. re-save permalink settings.
2. Are the Theme WOO template overrides up-to-date? Search for `theme/woocommerce/myaccount/` overrides.
3. Woocommerce --> Settings --> Accounts tab. Is your my-account page (with my-account shortcode) setup correctly?

Question:
What happens when you login through yourdomain.com/wp-login.php and then visit the my-account page?

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: thank you for your reply. There are no overrides for my-account, everything is run off the standard woocommerce setup. If i login as admin and visit /my-account/ it takes me to the my account page, there are no issues. only issues occur when trying to register/login is a normal shop user

Comment: I tried goinf to myaccount.co.uk/wp-login and logging in as a normal user (dumm account created) i get the same thing. loading for a while and then error message

Comment: Ok, so you can visit my account with an admin account. Hmm, it feels like another plugin is causing this, can you try again with all other plugins disabled?

Comment: I deactivated all the plugins and tried but it broke the site due to functions.php additions that I have made, relevant to different plugins. so no further forward. I did however manage to deactivate the plugins which are noted as untested with woocommerce latest release but that made no difference

Comment: Infact...Since deactivating and reactivatiing the plugins, I am now getting the issue with the whole site. All I can now access is my home page

Comment: Ok. I would still try to deactivate all pugins, and remove all your functions.php custom code. Please understand, i have almost no info to go on. What did you do in functions.php, which plugins are installed, etc.? If the problem stops when you deactivate everything you can then slowly activate all one by one. This way you can find the problem. Another suggestion is to activate wp_debug, check which logs are generated when you see the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far, Im new to coding so unsure what information to post. I will have a look and find out how to use wp-debug, could be a good option

Comment: I have found, using query monitor, that - Certificate verification disabled: sslverify=false. I am unsure what this means if i am honest but I know that an ssl certificate is mandatory for making payments... might this have an impact on myaccount?

Comment: I don't think that's the cause. Try the debug log. Set it to TRUE in your wp-config.php: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` Then install a [debug viewer plugin](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-log-viewer/)

Comment: Thanks again for your help so far @Bjorn. I have been trying different things all day, and as a result have amended my question